# Time of day - day distribution of episodes plot

Tags: r

I am measuring the duration of an episode in some workstations. I have the time stamp of the beginning of an episode and the end of the episode. I will like to come up with a plot where on the y axis is the time of day and on the x-axis the observation day. Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

For example I have

```
    id  start               end
    1   01/01/2010 10:00:00 02/01/2010 22:00:00
    1   04/01/2012 08:00:00 04/01/2012 14:00:00
```

And I would like to construct a plot like the attached

[image: Plot]

Any ideas how I could accomplish this? Unlike the attached graph, I would like to have minute accuracy/representation in the graph.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your example data isn't reproducible; I'm assuming that the dates are in day/month/year, but as displayed it's hard to tell. Also, date types are particular in `R`, so it is important to know which type you have.  So to start, I'll create a similar reproducible dataset:

```
DF <-
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L), start = structure(c(1262340000, 
1262592000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    end = structure(c(1262469600, 1262613600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), .Names = c("id", "start", "end"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like

```
> DF
  id               start                 end
1  1 2010-01-01 10:00:00 2010-01-02 22:00:00
2  1 2010-01-04 08:00:00 2010-01-04 14:00:00
```

Now, to draw this, we need to do several transformations. The day and the time must be split up since they are being plotted on different axes.

```
library("chron")
library("plyr")
DF$start.day <- as.Date(DF$start)
DF$end.day <- as.Date(DF$end)
DF$start.time <- as.chron(DF$start) - floor(as.chron(DF$start))
DF$end.time <- as.chron(DF$end) - floor(as.chron(DF$end))
```

Also, the date must be converted to an elapsed day.

```
t0 <- min(DF$start.day, DF$end.day)-1
DF$start.monitored.day <- as.numeric(DF$start.day - t0)
DF$end.monitored.day <- as.numeric(DF$end.day - t0)
```

Finally, periods which span past midnight must be broken up into multiple ranges such that each range is contained within a given day. This step is not very simple.

```
DF$index <- seq_len(nrow(DF))
DF <- ddply(DF, .(index), function(df) {
  if(df$start.monitored.day == df$end.monitored.day) {
    df 
  } else {
    data.frame(start.monitored.day = df$start.monitored.day : df$end.monitored.day,
               end.monitored.day = df$start.monitored.day : df$end.monitored.day,
               start.time = c(df$start.time, rep(times("00:00:00"), df$end.monitored.day-df$start.monitored.day)),
               end.time = times(c(rep(times("23:59:59"), df$end.monitored.day-df$start.monitored.day), df$end.time)),
               id = df$id,
               index = df$index)
  }
})
```

Now the data is in a format that can be plotted.

```
> DF[c("start.monitored.day", "end.monitored.day", "start.time", "end.time")]
  start.monitored.day end.monitored.day start.time end.time
1                   1                 1   10:00:00 23:59:59
2                   2                 2   00:00:00 22:00:00
3                   4                 4   08:00:00 14:00:00
```

I'm going to use `ggplot` to draw this because I'm more familiar with it and because I've done some [previous work on time scales with it](http://blog.ggplot2.org/post/29433173749/defining-a-new-transformation-for-ggplot2-scales-part).

Drawing from that blog post

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
timesreverse_trans <- function() {
    trans <- function(x) {-as.numeric(x)}
    inv <- function(x) {times(-x)}
    fmt <- function(x) {
        notone <- x != 1
        simplify <- !any(diff(x) < 1/(24*60))
        ifelse(notone, 
               format(x-floor(x), simplify=simplify),
               ifelse(simplify, "24:00", "24:00:00"))
    }
    trans_new("chrontimes-reverse",
              transform = trans,
              inverse = inv,
              breaks = pretty_breaks(),
              format = fmt,
              domain=c(0,1))
}
scale_y_times <- function(..., trans=NULL) {
    scale_y_continuous(..., trans=timesreverse_trans())
}
```

Which just leaves the actual plot

```
ggplot(DF) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start.monitored.day - 0.5,
                xmax = start.monitored.day + 0.5, 
                ymin = start.time,
                ymax = end.time)) +
  scale_y_times("Time") +
  scale_x_continuous("Monitored day")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Would something like this be also possible with base R?

Comment: @ECII I am sure it is possible, but I'm not as proficient with base graphics so I wouldn't know exactly how to approach it. I'll leave that to someone else to figure out.